# Addressing deprecated node module to switch to Node built-in module

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I'm trying to work with a package called eth-crypto which uses crypto node module. The app gives me this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in .../node_modules/eccrypto
```

And when I try to install crypto module via 'npm install crypto' the terminal gives me this message:

```
npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported.
It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
added 1 package, and audited 1568 packages in 3s
```

And nothing happens and I still get the first error. It seems that somehow I should switch to the module that's built-in Node but I don't know how and would appreciate anyone's help. my Node version is 18.13.0
I also get the same error "Can't resolve 'crypto' in .." when I use require('crypto') in any of my files.